# How do I read NaN (Sodium Nitride) in pandas from csv as a string instead of NaN (Not a Number)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am studying material informatics in python. I want to treat NaN (Sodium Nitride) as a chemical formula as a string, but it is taken as NaN (Not a Number).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', dtype={'formula': str})
print(df.loc[0]['formula'])
# >> nan
print(type(df.loc[0]['formula']))
# >> float
```

The csv file to be read is as follows

```
id,formula
1,NaN
2,NaHCO3
```

Comment: share your dataframe also..!

Comment: Sorry, I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defaut, [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) recognizes the following strings as NaN:

```
''
'#N/A'
'#N/A N/A'
'#NA'
'-1.#IND'
'-1.#QNAN'
'-NaN'
'-nan'
'1.#IND'
'1.#QNAN'
'<NA>'
'N/A'
'NA'
'NULL'
'NaN'
'n/a'
'nan'
'null'
```

Use the `na_values=[''], keep_default_na=False` option:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', na_values=[''], keep_default_na=False,
                 dtype={'formula': str})
```